# CMake relative include paths in C++

Tags: gcc, cmake

In the library I am using there is a trouble: all paths are relative.
I mean, file from `path1/path2/file.h` has `#include "interface.h"`, which (interface) is located in `anotherpath/anotherpath2/interface.h`.

Are there any ways how can I force linker to look for includes in different directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker couldn't care less for header files. It's the *compiler* you are looking at. (To be *really* nitpicking, it's the preprocessor. ;-) )

CMake has the `include_directories()` command:

```
include_directories( "anotherpath/anotherpath2" )
```

This, in `./CMakeLists.txt`, would make `#include "interface.h"` possible.

But is that what you really want? Usually, directories are used to segregate *modules*. `#include "anotherpath/anotherpath2/interface.h"` would send a *much* clearer message as to what is actually included here, and where a human could *find* that header file to look up its declarations. Perhaps a refactoring of your include statements would be better than to add lots of include directories to the CMake configuration...

Generally speaking, your question gives *very* little context, so it's hard to give advice.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Can I impl it somehow, so I don't touch library sources?

Comment: I mean that I need global project-wise cmake solution for a bunch of files like `interface.h`, so in **all** files it knows where to look for those specific files

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy: I honestly have no idea what you are talking about. The source is your own project, yes? Then you *have* to state the path, either in the CMake configuration (with `include_directories()`), *or* in the `#include` statement itself. Automagically searching for a given filename in all subdirectories is not the way to go. Anyway, voting to close as "unclear what you are asking".